# IntelliJ and built in Java Function Interface

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, functional-programming

My Spring components implement java.util.function.Function. The idea behind this is to force a functional style with small encapsulated functions.

```
@Component
public class MyFunction implements Function<In, Out> {
    public Out apply(In in) { .... }
}

// example usage
@RestController
public class MyApi {
    private MyFunction f;
    public void foo() {
        someList.stream()
            .map(f)
            . // whatever
    }
}
```

Two problems arise with IntelliJ 2018.1:

- "Find Usages" offers a choice to find usages of the base method. If I accidentally hit "Yes", IntelliJ finds a zillion usages and slows down until it almost freezes. Well, I should definitely select "No" here, but it is still a small issue.
- Using the function in a Stream (e.g. filter) with "Method Reference" (as IntelliJ suggests) is even more problematic. Using "Find Usages" and selecting "No" will not show the "real" usage(s) im looking for. This makes it hard to navigate in the code.

This leads me to my questions: Is it a good practice to use the built-in Function Interface or should I write my own Function without declaring it as a FunctionalInterface? Do you consider the mentioned problems as an IntelliJ bug? Are there workarounds you know of?

Comment: How does the call-site look like? Does it know it is dealing with `MyFunction`? Or does it get injected a generic `Function<In,Out>` ? If the former, you can at least find usages of the class `MyFunction` instead of the method `apply`.

Comment: Added example usage. Yes, usages of MyFunction will do the trick. But ... it feels so wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems valid to me, yet I try to avoid directly implementing `Function` as much as possible. The main reason is: **naming**.

I can understand that if a class has a meaningful name (e.g. `InOutMapFunction`), you might not feel the need for the method to have a meaningful name too. Still, I prefer names like `InOutMapper.mapInToOut` to `InOutMapFunction.apply`.

Besides, if you can think of more than one `InOutMapper`, make it an interface and let the component implement it.

Some may believe it's not worth to create your own functional interfaces if they "correspond" to the existing ones, but I hardly ever regret it, especially that in real uses cases, this impacts readability a lot, e.g. compare:

- `SomeParticularTypeContextFinder`, and
- `Function<SomeParticularType, SomeParticularTypeContext>`.

Here's how I'd implement your example:

```
@Component
public class PlainInOutMapper implements InOutMapper {
    @Override
    public Out mapInToOut(In in) { .... }
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface InOutMapper {
    Out mapInToOut(In in);
}

// example usage
@RestController
public class MyApi {
    private List<In> someList;

    private InOutMapper mapper;
    public void foo() {
        someList.stream()
                .map(mapper::mapInToOut)
                . // whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for answering. However, I do not see a benefit with well-named methods, since @FunctionalInterface will result in someList.stream().map(mapper) anyway (short for mapper::mapInToOut). Therefore, I will have the same IntelliJ issues. Of course, I could stop using the shorthand for mapper:mapInToOut.

Comment: @saimonsez Note that since `InOutMapper` doesn't extend `Function<In, Out>`, you can't just call `.map(mapper)` (it won't even compile) - it must be `.map(mapper::mapInToOut)`.

Comment: Good to know. I have not tried it and thought this is related to @FunctionalInterface instead of Function. Will give it a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the scope of the search via the 'Find Usages Settings' (default on Windows: CTRL+ALT+SHFT+F7)

[image]

The settings apply to the search via ALT+F7 as well as the Mouse Wheel Click one. Maybe limiting it to your current module does the trick?

Comment: Thx. This solves issue #1, but not #2. I really think this is an IntelliJ bug.